# Check the definition of "pointwise bounded under $d$"

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, definition, arzela-ascoli

[image]

The above definition is from Munkre's topology in Section 45.I  want to know whether the definition is correct?I think it contains  a typo, in place of '$a$' it should be '$x$'...

Please clarify this

Comment: Yes, it should either be "if for each $a \in X$..." or it should be $\mathcal F_x = \{f(x) | f \in \mathcal F\}$. Otherwise the definition makes no sense.

Comment: @Lukas You should give an official answer.